# How to get the AppBar in Androidx?

Tags: android, androidx

My project is entirely built on Androidx, but I can't seem to get an activity's AppBar programmatically, which I really need to.

I'm pretty sure it's a dependency issue, but even upon fixing that, as per this official migration guide (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), I can't seem to get the AppBar in my activity.

This is the default dependency Android Studio added in my app's Gradle file:
`implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'`
And this is the new dependency that I added as per the migration documentation:
`implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`

This is the code I would use in pre-Androidx days to get an activity's AppBar:
`android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();`

But now I have absolutely no idea how to get an AppBar with Androix since I keep getting errors here, like 'cannot resolve symbol v7' or 'cannot resolve symbol support'.

Also, if I change the v7 in this line of code to v4 while using the default androix dependency of v4 legacy, I get an error on `.ActionBar`

Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here, and how I can fix this with Androidx?

Comment: You don't need the fully qualified name, just call 'ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();'

Comment: @IvanWooll you're right, that worked! Thank you so much! Don't know why I didn't think of it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBar` as you are not using the support libraries anymore. You can just use `ActionBar`

```java
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```